# dsr files won't load or display in Project Explorer - No Errors are displayed

Tags: vb6, designer

I am working with 2 computers. Both are desktop machines using Windows 10. Computer #1 is a new computer remote from my location and I control it using TeamViewer. Computer #2 is located in my home controlled locally. Both computers have had VB6 installed using the article by Dan Brust (  )as a guide which includes using the installer program "VS6installer.exe" by Giorgio Brausi.

When trying to load and run the same VB6 project on both computers, Computer #1 only shows one of many dsr files (DataEnvironmentReport.dsr) in Project Explorer and the rest are apparently not loading. All other frm, bas, and cls files load and display correctly. No errors were displayed.

When loading and running the VB6 Project on Computer #2, all works fine with ALL dsr items showing in Project Explorer.

I suspect that the dll which loads dsr files is either defective or not registered on computer #1 or, maybe it is some other file. I have cross checked the Reference list and Component list on both computers, and they appear to be identical. I have even copied the VB6 install file created by computer #1 to #2 and re-installed VB6 on #2.  Loading and running the project proceedes normally with no problems.

Would someone (with a lot more smarts than me) please provide your thoughts or suggestions for the following questions:

1) Do ALL dll, ocx, etc. files need to be registered before my VB6 installation will work? If not all, how do I know the correct set that do require registration? How can I check which ones are registered and which ones are not?

2) Could operating #1 by using TeamViewer cause an incombatibility that messes up the VB6 install on #1?

3) Any other suggestions as to what is causing Computer #1 to not load all dsr files, and what else I might try to fix this problem?

- Matt -

Comment: #1 yes, look in the VBP file to see which ones are required.

Comment: #2 I doubt it.. probably not